# ASP.NET The server tag is not well formed

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code, I'm trying to disable the radio button when the condition is true. However when I add in the `<%# Eval("category_id").ToString().Equals("5") ? "disabled" : "" %>` statement I'm getting the `The server tag is not well formed` error.

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. If I removed the Code snippet outside of the radio button tag the word `disabled` displays as text on the screen, but as soon as I move it in the radio button tag I get the error.

```
   <asp:RadioButton  
        ID="Status_C" 
        runat="server" 
        Text="C" 
        GroupName="Status" 
        Style="color: green;" 
        <%# Eval("category_id").ToString().Equals("5") ? "disabled" : "" %> 
    />
```

Comment: Isn't there an [`Enabled` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled) which you can set with `Eval`?

Comment: Is this code within a repeater ?

Comment: Well the warning is correct, `<asp:RadioButton ... disabled />` isn't well a valid ASP.NET tag. I think you want `Enabled="..."`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:RadioButton  
        ID="Status_C" 
        runat="server" 
        Text="C" 
        GroupName="Status" 
        Style="color: green;" 
        Enabled='<%# !(Eval("category_id").ToString().Equals("5")) %>'
    />
```